# Subject Oriented or Refinements with builtin python objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, scope, roles, lookup

Goal:
Extend abitrary classes with roles that are only valid in a certain context.

This works:

```
# from https://github.com/niccokunzmann/wwp/blob/master/C_builtinTypes.py
from relative import roleOf, useRoles

@roleOf(int)
class NaturalNumber:
    # int gets successor only in this module
    @property
    def successor(self):
        return 1 + self

@roleOf(tuple)
@roleOf(list)
class MyList:
    @property
    def first(self):
        return self[0]

@useRoles
def test():
    # this is possible if we recompile the code objects
    i = 1
    print(type(i))
    assert i.successor == 2
    assert i.successor.successor == 3
    assert isinstance(i, int) # EDIT3 works
    # check for identity
    t = (3,)
    assert t.first == 3
    l = list() 
    l.append(3)
    assert l.first == 3 # this assertion fails
    assert l.first == 2 + 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

My Problem:

**EDIT2:** I wrote 100 lines of code for usual python classes to make this work but for builtins I added 250 lines and there is no complete solution in sight.

I can not create custom classes for builtin objects as I can with pure python classes as [link:A](https://github.com/niccokunzmann/wwp/blob/master/A.py) or [link:B](https://github.com/niccokunzmann/wwp/blob/master/B.py).
This is because the compiler puts them everywhere:

```
>>> test.__code__.co_consts
(None, 1, 2, 3, (3,), 3)
```

I can not do the replacement in code objects with lists because they are built in the code.

These are my questions because I can not estimate it:

- What are the places I have to look for builtin objects to replace them with wrappers so I can add roles to them?
- would an C-extension help me patch the attribute lookup so I can make roles for booleans
- will I need to compile my own python to make this idea work?
- is there another solution?

**EDIT 1**

This is one of my Use-cases: `1 .successor.successor == 3`.
I want to make it easy to have small domains that do not interfer with the whole program = keep classes slim.

For example I want to make numbers callable to create a lambda calculus.

I want to have slim classes and for special use cases I want to extend them by roles so I can call custom functions on them.
I the end something between [Data-Context-Interaction](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Context_Interaction) and Context-Oriented Programming should come out.

Comment: If you want to change type of objects created by literals; you might need an on-the-fly source rewrite e.g., see how [`codeblocks` implemented](http://mtomassoli.wordpress.com/2012/04/20/code-blocks-in-python/)

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide some more information on your use-case?  I think you want to look into metaclasses but not sure without more information on your specific needs.  And I think there's something wrong or too clever if you want to replace builtins.

Comment: this talk at minute 33 was helpful http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ANhTacigaf8&feature=youtu.be

Comment: I really want to make this possible with builtins, too. it is working with usal classes very well but builtins are essential I think. Could also be a bad idea to change builtins that way. Could be ok if one can wrap them explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to look into Abstract Base Classes:

http://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html

Comment: `assert isinstance(i, int)` works for me already. Do you have a specific idea of what I may find there to help me? I know the concept but can not see how it should be applied.

Comment: This only helps me with `__isinstance__` but not with adding new functions to tuple