# Changing methods of Python objects (reclassing?)

Tags: python, oop, constructor

The question is an extension of [Reclassing an instance in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990758/reclassing-an-instance-in-python?lq=1) where the OP very nicely explains the situation (class in foreign lib, subclass in own code).
However, there remain some open details in the answers IMHO:

- if I reclass parent objects to child objects, is it valid at all to have a child constructor? After all, due to the absence of a copy-costructor (together with all problems of deep vs. shallow copying) I can't expect to correctly construct complete parent objects  (even if I know the parent-constructor signature, see self._secret in the example). Would it be wise to lock the child constructor (by throwing an exception there e.g.)?
- how does C++ handle such a situation (inheritance)?
- do I break various OOP principles with the code? Is this a slap in the face of some design pattern? The basic idea, to retrofit some minor details of an object to my needs doesn't look so sinful after all.

## foreign_lib.py:

```
lib_data = "baz"

class parent:
    def __init__(self,foo,bar):
        self._foo = foo
        self._bar = bar

    def do_things(self):
        print(self._foo,self._bar)

    def do_other_things(self,one2one_reference): 
       # this parent and the one2one_reference shall
       # live in a 1:1 relationship
        self._secret = one2one_reference  # maybe ugly,but not in  
                                          # our hands to correct it

def some_lib_func():
    p = parent("foo","bar")
    p.do_other_things(lib_data)
    return p
```

## my_code.py:

```
class child(foreign_lib.parent):
    def do_things: # but differently!
        print(42)
        super().do_things()

    # do_other_things() shall be inherited  as is

    def __init__(self,p):
        # out of luck here, no copy-constructor for parent?

    @classmethod
    def convert_to_child(cls,a_parent):
        a_parent.__class__ = cls

a_child = child(some_lib_func())  # will not work correctly
a_child = child.convert_to_child(some_lib_func()) # maybe this one?
```

Comment: Adapters and wrappers are nice patterns. You might want to consider them. :-)

Comment: As Lennart mentioned Python has a good support for delegation so a simple adapter / wrapper might be the good solution. Another - less clean but sometimes a real life-saver - solution is monkeypatching.

Comment: Some additional points in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464061/cast-base-class-to-derived-class-python-or-more-pythonic-way-of-extending-class

Comment: I think you can totally do this in your code if you are the only one doing this to the object. Here is my wish for subjectivity in an objective world: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14946636/subject-oriented-or-refinements-with-builtin-python-objects